# Why doesn't rpm or dnf recognize default perl?

Tags: fedora, yum, perl, rpm, dependencies

I have an `rpm` package I built which depends on `perl`. When I try to install this package it fails:

```
$ rpm -ivh <package-y>
error: Failed dependencies:
    perl is needed by package-y.x86_64
```

If I run `dnf info perl` it shows that perl is not installed but I am able to find `perl` on my system:

```
which perl
perl: /usr/bin/perl /opt/lampp/bin/perl /usr/share/man/man1/perl.1.gz
```

And checking for perl's version:

```
$ perl --version

This is perl 5, version 26, subversion 2 (v5.26.2) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
(with 47 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)

Copyright 1987-2018, Larry Wall

Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License or the
GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5 source kit.

Complete documentation for Perl, including FAQ lists, should be found on
this system using "man perl" or "perldoc perl".  If you have access to the
Internet, point your browser at http://www.perl.org/, the Perl Home Page.
```

It seems that perl is installed by default on my system (fedora) but why does the package manager (dnf or rpm) not recognise it?

Comment: If the metadata of a package says it depends on `perl`, it means you must have on your system a package that is either named exactly like `perl-<version>.<architecture>` or has `Provides: perl` in its metadata. What does the `rpm -q perl` say? Or `rpm -qf /usr/bin/perl`?

Comment: So you are saying that I must have a `.rpm` package named `perl` in order for perl not to be classed as a missing dependency? Isn't this odd when perl is installed by default on my system. And are you suggesting I create a dummy package named `perl`? What if I `dnf install perl`, will it cause conflicts with my pre-installed default `perl`?

Comment: Or a package that includes `Provides: perl` in its RPM package metadata, yes. `rpm -qf /usr/bin/perl` should tell you the actual name of your current perl RPM, and `rpm -q --provides <package name>` will tell the Provides keywords it has. I would not suggest a solution before knowing what the initial state actually is.

Comment: `$ rpm -q perl
package perl is not installed`
`$ rpm -qf /usr/bin/perl
perl-interpreter-5.26.2-412.fc28.x86_64`. Yes, more info is needed for a solution. Is `rpm -q --provides` for the package which needs perls as a dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying dependencies to something like Perl can be very complex. For example, when your `package-y` says it requires `perl`, does it mean Perl 5.x or Perl 6.x? Does it need a specific minor version of Perl 5.x? Or would an ancient Perl 4.x be enough for it?

[Here's the part of Fedora Packaging Guidelines that concerns Perl.](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Perl) As you can see, it is rather complicated. It looks like your `package-y` is not following those guidelines. Is it intended for Fedora specifically, or is it packaged for some other random distribution?

The best way to fix it without repackaging `package-y` would be to find out what specific requirements your `package-y` actually has for Perl, then create a dummy package with a name like `dependencies-for-package-y.rpm` with both `Provides: perl` (to allow the dummy package to satisfy the requirements of `package-y`) and at least `Requires: perl(:VERSION) >= <minimum required Perl version for package-y>` (to supply the information of `package-y`'s actual requirements to the package manager).

If your `package-y` includes pre-compiled Perl modules, or links into `libperl.so`, the dummy package should also have the appropriate `Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_<version number>)` keyword. That way, if your current Perl is updated in a way that breaks module compatibility e.g. because of a security issue, your package manager will tell you that you must either also update `package-y`, remove it, or defer updating your Perl because updating it would break `package-y`.

Your current `/usr/bin/perl` is actually supplied by a package named `perl-interpreter`. [You can see the Requires and Provides keywords that package has in rpmfind.net.](https://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/fedora/updates/28/x86_64/Packages/p/perl-interpreter-5.26.2-412.fc28.x86_64.html)

Comment: great answer. Yes, `dnf info perl-interpreter` shows it is in fact the perl that I have installed. Did I mention when I say built an __rpm__ package, I mean using a program called [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm "fpm packaging tool") not using something like `rpmbuild`. Based on this, it is not too difficult to rebuild the package but as a long term solution may be there's a better solution?

Comment: The absolute best solution would be repackaging `package-y` so that has its dependencies specified according to the Fedora Packaging Guidelines for Perl. I missed the fact that you said you had actually built `package-y`. You might be able to "disassemble" the package generated with `fpm`, make the necessary dependency modifications and then rebuild it with `rpmbuild`.

Comment: That was exactly what I did, repackaged with `perl-interpreter` replacing `perl` as one of the dependencies, and it worked. I'm not familiar with `rpmbuild` but now I know a bit about it I may look into using it. What would you say is the difference between `rpmbuild` and `fpm` when generating `rpm` packages?

Comment: `rpmbuild` is the full-featured standard tool that is specific for `rpm` packages. It would be the "native" tool for rpm. `fpm` attempts to be an universal automated easy tool for multiple packaging formats, but its automation seems to currently fall somewhat short of the goal, at least for Perl packages. Reading its feature list, it seems to me its developer has provided some advanced functionality for packaging Python software, but not (yet?) for Perl.